# Reading files into an array of listboxes

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am attempting to read a text file I have created into an array of listboxes which I have declared globally. I'm trying to read into one listbox a Genre title and Track titles, with each Listbox containing a different genre etc. for a jukebox program. The text file reads as follows:
5 // Number of Genre
6 // Number of Tracks in Genre 1
Genre Title 1
Track title 1
3 // Number of tracks in Genre 2
 etc.

Here is the code I have tried:

```
string strNum_gen;
string strNum_tracks;
string title;
string track;

StreamReader myInputStream = File.OpenText(MediaApplicationPath      + "Media.txt");

strNum_gen = myInputStream.ReadLine();
Number_Of_Genre = Int32.Parse(strNum_gen);

for (int Genre_Number = 1; Genre_Number<=Number_Of_Genre; Genre_Number++)
   {
     Load_JukeBox_Library();

     Jukebox_Library[0] = new ListBox();

     strNum_tracks = myInputStream.ReadLine();
     int num_tracks = Int32.Parse(strNum_tracks);

     title = myInputStream.ReadLine();
     Jukebox_Library[0].Items.Add(title);

     for (int Track_Number = 1; Track_Number<=num_tracks; Track_Number++)
       {
          track = myInputStream.ReadLine();
          Jukebox_Library[0].Items.Add(track);
       }
      }
        Genre_List_Listbox.Items.Add(Jukebox_Library);
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Exactly what problem do you have? Does the code compile - if not show us the error messages. Do you get an exception thrown - if so show us the full information.

Comment: Please fix your formatting while you are at it. You are asking for others to help you, at least show you have put some basic effort in on your part